# Matlab s2p file

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to build a s2p file in simulink using the block "To File" but gives me an odd file with random characters like

fs%($&%%(&
[image]

Which looks like when I try to open a jpeg file with block note.
I'm trying a simple RF layout with a single resistive divider and the input and output ports like in figure
[image]

anyone knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `To File` block writes a .mat (binary) data file.  Opening one as a text file is always going to show *odd random characters*

To see what's in the file you need to use `load` to load the saved signal(s) into the MATLAB Workspace.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a s2p file inside Simulink instead use a `To workspace` block? Because this block gives me a timeseries type of variable.

Comment: By default `To Workspace` gives a time series - it can be changed to give other formats (for numeric data) such as `Structure with Time` and `Array`.  I don't know what a `.s2p`file looks like, but know that `To Workspace` does not (and will not) give it to you.